# Can't add/clone arraylist from update (Observer) method

Tags: java, arraylist, observable

I'm making a small program using Observer/Observable, which you can input your ID, first name and last name and grade then save it. Then you can search if this ID is found.

What I'm doing here is making an ArrayList in three classes, the Observer and Observable and `EnteringValues`.

I have an Observable class which is `SujetConcret` and Observer class which is `Search`

And there is a class `EnteringValues` which I added a listener to the save button:

> EnteringValues.java

```
public class saveListener implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event){
    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);
        tid.write(fileWriter);
        fileWriter.write("\n");
        fileWriter.close();
        ar.add(tid.getText());
        s.setValue(ar);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }   
}
```

Here as you can see I've added the ID from the `JTextfield` to the ArrayList(String) `ar` and using `s.setValue(ar)` to add it to the Observable class `SujetConcret`

> SujetConcret.java (Observable)

```
public class SujetConcret extends Observable {
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

void setValue(ArrayList<String> arx){
    ar=arx;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

ArrayList getValue(){
    return ar;
   }
}
```

> Search.java (Observer)

```
public void update(Observable ob, Object o1) {
        ax = (ArrayList<String>) ((SujetConcret)ob).getValue().clone();
}
```

> Calling `ax` to see if `ax` took values from the Observable ArrayList in `Search` class

```
ArrayList<String> ax = new ArrayList<String>(); //Under public class Search extends..
Search(SujetConcret s){
    this.s=s;
        for(int i=0; i<s.getValue().size();i++){
        System.out.println(ax.get(i));
    }
}
```

***The Problem :***

What I'm facing here is in `Search` class, I'm trying to update (after being notified) the ArrayList(String) `ax` created in `Search` class. I was testing to see if the values from `EnteringValues` ArrayList `ar` is added to the Observable Arraylist using `for` loop and printing all the values in `Search` class using `s.getValue().get(i)` and it works.

But in the update method for Observer I tried to clone it and add it but I'm having Exceptions when I run the program.

I tried in the `update` method to not include the `Observable` so I replaced this method by `ax.add("1")` and it gave me `IndexOutOfBoundsException` now I could realise that the error is from the ArrayList `ax` and not from the Observable ArrayList.

Comment: what kind of exception are you getting?

Comment: @ChrisGong I'm having ```IndexOutOfBounds``` then I try to add a value to the ```Search``` class ArrayList ```ax``` and print it, it only shows the value added without the values imported from the Observable ```SujetConcret``` ArrayList

Comment: can you add the code where you print out `ax`?

Comment: can you change the condition in the for loop to `i<ax.size()` since you're looping through `ax` technically. Unless you want to loop through `s.getValue()` instead.

Comment: @ChrisGong I changed it to ```i<ax.size()``` but it's not printing even tho as I edited in the question that i changed the ```update``` method to only ```ax.add("1")``` to see if it would add the string but id doesnt work.